# How to add CUDA 7.0 acceleration to existing project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

According to http://docs.nvidia.com/ all you have to do to include cuda in your project is to:

> Open the Visual Studio project, right click on the project name, and select Build Customizations..., then select the CUDA Toolkit version you would like to target.

I am following "Your First CUDA C Program" from CUDACast and I see in the video that VisualStudio still marks red all the instructions from CUDA, so I thought it was fine when I was writing in my project. But when I've built it I've seen errors in every line using their instructions.
Do I need to link some other libraries myself?

I've noticed two new sections when I open project's properties:
"CUDA C/C++" and "CUDA Linker"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are building a cuda runtime project, at a minimum you will need to link in `cudart.lib` the cuda runtime library.  This involves specifying the path to that library as well as identify the library itself in "Additional Dependencies".  If you don't do this, but use CUDA API functions such as `cudaMalloc`, you will get errors at link phase.  (If you are getting errors prior to link phase, there is some other issue.)

I suggest you review a [cuda sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#abstract) such as vectorAdd, to learn how a cuda Visual Studio project is structured.

You will also probably want to be sure you have followed all steps in the [windows getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#abstract) properly, which includes building and running sample codes.

The reason that the library step is not shown (needed) in the video sequence is that your method of starting the project in Visual Studio (start an arbitrary project, then select CUDA build customizations) is different than that shown in the video (start a project by selecting the CUDA Runtime custom toolchain).

Comment: The sample code projects worked so I looked at their config and added to my project properties: under C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories "$(CudaToolkitDir)/include;"
and under Linker -> Additional Library Directories "$(CudaToolkitLibDir);"