# Error when using NVTX library in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cuda

The following error I am getting when I attempt to use CUDA NVTX library in Visual studio 2013.

```
Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-lnvToolsEx'
```

Steps:

1. PATH variable in the host windows machine has been set correctly to the location of the library.
2. The library options has been added at Property_Pages -> Confuguration Properties -> Cuda C/C++ -> Host -> Additional compiler options -> "-lnvToolsExt".

I suspect the issue is mostly due to Adding the library to the project. Could someone please point me at the right direction.

Comment: That's not the correct way to add a library dependency in visual studio.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you please tell me the correct way to do it in msvs2013.

Comment: I think if you try a search such as "stackoverflow how to add a library in visual studio cuda" you will figure it out.  You would add the library in question in the same place and way that cudart.lib, for example, is added to any CUDA project.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058864/how-to-include-libraries-in-visual-studio-2012) and/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736089/how-to-add-cuda-7-0-acceleration-to-existing-project) and/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778799/how-do-i-start-a-cuda-app-in-visual-studio-2010)  should have the information you need.  This question is arguably a duplicate of the first one I linked.

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella. It works.

Answer (score -1):

This is a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058864/how-to-include-libraries-in-visual-studio-2012) . Credits to @Robert Crovella for pointing it out.

Comment: This reads more like a comment, maybe expand it to include the salient points of the duplicate that are applicable.